# Text file to Text file String Conversion Using Powershell CSV Objects

Tags: powershell, csv, object, text, properties

I can change the column order of text in a file:

```
001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street 
002 BROWN James 101 Browns Road
003 CAMPBELL Colin 57 Camp Avenue
```

to have the first names listed before surnames using the following:

```
$Data = Import-CSV C:\test\test6\sqlInsertList.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header "Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6"

# attempt to output with Surname/FirstName (columns 2 & 3) reversed 
[array]$fileStore = $Data | Select-Object Col1,Col3,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6 | Export-CSV C:\test\test6\newSqlInsertList.txt -append
```

The output being:

```
"Col1","Col3","Col2","Col4","Col5","Col6"
"001","Alan","AALTON","25","Every","Street"
"002","James","BROWN","101","Browns","Road"
"003","Colin","CAMPBELL","57","Camp","Avenue"
```

But if I'm to process this output to a string format I am stuck trying to expand each `Colx` property like:

```
$Data = Import-CSV C:\test\test6\sqlInsertList.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header "Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6"

    # attempt to output with Surname/FirstName (columns 2 & 3) reversed 
    [array]$fileStore = $Data | Select-Object Col1,Col3,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6 
    
    # first attempt worked 
    $test = $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col1
    $test += ' '
    $test += $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col3
    $test += ' '
    $test += $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col2
    $test += ' '
    $test += $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col4
    $test += ' '
    $test += $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col5
    $test += ' '
    $test += $fileStore[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col6
    $test
```

To output:

```
002 James BROWN 101 Browns Road
```

I can't store the objects `Colx` in an array to loop through them. So the solution I have so far is cumbersome and simply doesn't seem right.

The solutions seem to be:

1. Somehow intercept the `Export-CSV C:\test\test6\newSqlInsertList.txt -append` to remove double quotes & commas
2. Or find a way to expand all the column properties in a better way than I have shown

I would appreciate if anyone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to get what you're looking for, to be honest, I don't understand why would you want to export the output the way you want it instead of a proper Csv.

```bash
$headers  = "A","B","C","D","E","F"
$newOrder = "A","C","B","D","E","F"

Import-CSV C:\test\test6\sqlInsertList.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header $headers | ForEach-Object {
    $(foreach($i in $newOrder) { $_.$i }) -join ' '
} | Set-Content newfile.someextension
```

To give context on what the code is doing:

1. The outer [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) loop is enumerating each object from the collection (the Csv).
2. The inner [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) loop is getting the **property values** of each object from the collection (in the desired order).
3. All the output from the inner loop is being *collected* with [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) and after the enumeration is done, all captured output is being joined by a space `' '` with the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Thank you @Santiago. Success. Yes I take your point re: outputting other than CSV file type. But my priority is understanding how your example works. I take it that `ForEach-Object {$(foreach($i in $newOrder) { $_.$i }) -join ' '}` The object being a group of space delimited text arranged in columns. Where each member of a new order is assigned as a property of the original object `{ $_.$i }` Same text but new order. That's the best I can do for now.

Comment: @Dave happy to help. I added some explanation to the code, hope is easy to follow